# Ошибка при компиляции flet в apk

Tags: python, apk, flet

Компилирую свое приложение flet в apk-файл. До этого все работало, но после того, когда я добавил `requests` в `requirements.txt`, то начала появляться ошибка:

```
Flet app package app/app.zip was not created.
```

Полный лог:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\NeoTelecom> flet build apk 
Creating Flutter bootstrap project...OK
Customizing app icons and splash images...OK
Generating app icons...OK
Generating splash screens...OK
Packaging Python app...Flet app package app/app.zip was not created.
```

Если я удаляю `requirements.txt` из директории, то все работает, но при запуске приложения выводит `ModuleNotFoundError`
Содержимое `requirements.txt`:

```
requests==2.31.0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй: "flet build apk {папка приложение}".
Например: Если ты создал приложение помощью команды "flet create myapp". То твоя команда будет "flet build apk myapp"

Answer (score 0):

Если сделать сборку так:

```
flet build apk --verbose
```

, то в выводе видно, что у файла *requirements.txt* должна быть кодировка UTF-8, а при выгрузке этого файла через:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

кодировка получается UTF-16. Из-за этого и возникает:

> Error: FileSystemException: Failed to decode data using encoding 'utf-8'

Для решения этой проблемы у файла *requirements.txt* нужно поменять кодировку с UTF-16 на UTF-8.

Comment: Мне надо записать его через UTF-8, то есть `with open('requirements.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fl:    fl.write('requests==2.31.0')`?

Comment: Ага, или в блокноте сохранить с другой кодировкой